# Is there any in-memory engine in Yugabyte

Tags: yugabytedb

Do we have any in-memory kind of engine just like Couchbase provides an in-memory layer and all the data sits over in-memory and if the node reboots your data is gone. we don't want to use yedis for caching layer if it provides any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, YugabyteDB doesn't have an *in-memory only* engine.

It is a distributed database with persistence/replication as some of its core-tenets. You can run it with replication factor of 1, but it is designed with persistence in mind. If a node restarts, the data will still be around, and the in-memory block cache will be warmed up on demand very quickly.

Having said that, YugabyteDB is designed for very good read performance (sub-millisec latencies) even when data set doesn't fit entirely in RAM.

References:

- "[Extending RocksDB for Speed & Scale](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/e6c4cb215effcb181cd5772159c82e4f6f8a0d2e/docs/extending-rocksdb.md#-extending-rocksdb-for-speed--scale-)" describes some of this work done in YugabyteDB's storage engine that's based on RocksDB.
- This [post](https://blog.yugabyte.com/achieving-sub-ms-latencies-on-large-data-sets-in-public-clouds/) describes performance measurements for a random read workload where the data set does not fit in RAM.